# Low sample size as cause of both Type I and Type II errors

Tags: binomial-distribution, sample-size, inference

It is intuitive that, with a small sample size, extreme results are more probable. For instance, the probability of 4 out of 4 balls drawn from an urn of black&white balls to be all white is higher than with 7 out of 7, as the binomial distribution tells us.

Nonetheless, when using statistical inference to estimate a population parameter from a sample parameter, a low sample size seems to be criticised not because it makes a "fluke" more likely (Type I error) but because it makes detecting a real but small effect more unlikely (Type II error).

This seems contradictory. Are these in fact two sides of the same coin, e.g. both are cases of a low sample making the conclusion depend too much upon sampling error (the luck of the draw)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but my question isn't a duplicate of the question you suggest any more than any other random question that you will find that contains similar key words ("sample size", "type I error" etc).

Comment: I disagree - StudentT identified a question which is sufficiently similar to yours that the answers there directly address the issue you raise (explaining why it isn't the same for both). Please read the answers there and if you have unresolved issues, feel free to either edit your question or post a new one.